# Why doesn't ACCEPTINVCHARS work here?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm getting load errors when trying to load data into Redshift.  My error is:

```
Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x24 found at location nnn
```

I'm using this command which includes the ACCEPTINVCHARS option, and the column in question is defined as VARCHAR(80)

```
copy <dest_tbl> from <S3 source> 
CREDENTIALS <my_credentials>  IGNOREHEADER 1 ENCODING UTF8 
IGNOREBLANKLINES NULL AS '\\N' 
EMPTYASNULL BLANKSASNULL gzip ACCEPTINVCHARS timeformat 'auto' 
dateformat 'auto' MAXERROR 1 compupdate on;
```

The errors look like this in vi

[image: Unexpected chars - vi]

An octal dump looks like this:
[image: Unexpected chars - octal]

I'm not understanding why this is failing given the ACCEPTINVCHARS [documentation at Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-acceptinvchars)     Can anyone suggest a solution or a workaround?   Put another way, what do I need to do to ensure that Redshift accepts this string in this field?

Comment: What is the format of your file? Your COPY statement is not specifying a format, so it is defaulting to UTF-8 with pipe ( | ) delimiters.

Comment: It's not defaulting to those parameters, they are explicit.  UTF-8 is in the OP,  but in trying to mask my credentials I mistakenly deleted the DELIMITER '|' parameter in the COPY statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Octal dump shows they are null values (NUL) which are treated as line terminator by redshift copy command.

Use NULL AS '\0' instead default '\N',

Comment: That was it !!  Thanks.

Comment: So apparently this does not work if I am also using `JSON` option. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @lollerskates, did you get any work around for JSON?