# Redshift error on copy for null value in data - "Invalid null byte - field longer than 1 byte"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, utf-8, amazon-redshift

When using copy command to move data from S3 to redshift, I am getting following error

> Invalid null byte - field longer than 1 byte

Copy command I am using is:

```
copy sample_table from 's3://<bucket_name>/<sample_json>.gz'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<key>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret>'
json 'auto' gzip acceptinvchars;
```

`sample_table` in which I want to put data has 2 columns

```
id integer,
name varchar(200)
```

I think, the problem is caused by null character in the data. As suggested [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-acceptinvchars), I tried using `acceptinvchars` in copy command, but its throwing same error.
Sample data I am trying to load is:

```
{"id":2, "name":"test"}
{"id":3, "name":"\u0000\n\test2"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the logs in stl_load_error for more details, also add maxerror 10 or something to your query to see how many records fail and then fix the problem based on logs. I also think you have to give AS along with acceptinvchars.  - `json 'auto' gzip acceptinvchars AS '-'`

Comment: `\u0000` is the issue. This is a NUL of more than 1 byte. FWIW, you will _not_ be able to load an NUL values into Redshift. c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297955/why-doesnt-acceptinvchars-work-here/43301155#43301155